# Opencart check if guest checkout

Tags: opencart

I am making some modifications to an Opencart installation and one is to show a step 1 of x etc.

Is there a way to check if the user is using the guest checkout as this seems to have one less step than the registered user checkout. I think because they combine payment and shipping address into one page. So what I would like is that if using guest checkout show 1 of 3, 2 of 3 etc otherwise show 1 of 4, 2 of 4 etc.

Thanks

Comment: the code is just in front of you, can't you read it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if a user is logged in (registered) you can use

```
$this->customer->isLogged()
```

which will return `true` if they're logged in (registered) or `false` if it's a guest

Comment: Whether or not this question was off-topic, I had exactly the same question and this answer was perfect.